# Autoscroll to bottom of DIV after updating, only if already at bottom of DIV before update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The code below adds content to a DIV and then scrolls it to show the new content:

```
<div id="Scrollable" style="height:400px; overflow:scroll;>
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
</div>

<script>
// Should DIV be auto scrolled?
var autoScroll = true;

// Add new content
$('#Scrollable').append('5<br />6<br />');

if ( autoScroll ){ // Scroll to bottom of DIV
    $('#Scrollable').animate({ scrollTop: $('#Scrollable').prop('scrollHeight') });
}
</script>
```

What I need is a check at the `var autoScroll = true` stage to detect whether or not the DIV is currently scrolled to the bottom. So that after the new content is added, **it will only autoscroll if the DIV was at the bottom before.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What problems did you encounter when trying to write this? Here's a jsFiddle example, based off the first result I found in Google for "jquery check if div is scrolled to bottom". It seems to work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/QB75Z/

And here's a link to the article I found: http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/

**EDIT**: Here's the actual code from the jsFiddle I posted, in case someone's searching and jsFiddle disappears. Have a scrollable div (give it a height and `overflow-y: scroll`) with an id of scrollable, and an inner div inside that with a class of inner. Then you can determine whether the div is scrolled to the bottom or not by using the following code:

```
var scrollable = $('#scrollable');
var inner = $('#scrollable > .inner');

// check if div is scrolled to bottom before addition of new content
var atBottom = Math.abs(inner.offset().top) + scrollable.height() + scrollable.offset().top >= inner.outerHeight();

// add additional content to .inner here

if ( atBottom ) {
  // do stuff like scroll to bottom etc
}
```

Comment: My question isn't how to scroll to the bottom, but to detect when a DIV is already scrolled to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example of this listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

> The following equivalence returns true if an element is at the end of its scroll, false if it isn't.

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

The demo listed on that page is very helpful as well.